# How to keep scaling always at 1 on FabricJS [Edited]

Tags: fabricjs

I need in my application made in fabricJS, that when I modify an object with the scaling handlers, the scaling stays in 1, and that the size of the object takes the value of the height multiplied by scaleX. I can apply the same for the width. But I can not apply this in the images. How can I fix this?

I leave an example fiddle for a square, and an image, so that you can see the result.

The result in the image is similar to a crop, and I can not avoid this, because apparently, when I modify the container of the image, the _element property that also contains `scaleX` and `scaleY` does not change, so the image is not resized inside the container.
Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samael205/86ywhzz5/1/).

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    left: 200,
    top: 200,
    angle: 0,
    fill: 'rgba(0,0,255,1)',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

canvas.add(rect1);
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function(myImg) {
    //i create an extra var for to change some image properties
    var img1 = myImg.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: 150,
        height: 150
    });
    canvas.add(img1);
});
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
    /*if(e.target != null){
        //alert(e.target.width*e.target.scaleX);

    }*/
    //console.log(e.target);
    canvas.getActiveObjects().forEach(function(obj) {
        //if(obj.get('type')!='image'){
        obj.set('width', obj.width * obj.scaleX, obj);
        obj.set('height', obj.height * obj.scaleY, obj);
        //if(obj.get('type')!='image'){
        obj.scaleX = 1;
        obj.scaleY = 1;
        //}else{
        //  obj.scaleX = 1;
        //  obj.scaleY = 1;
        //  obj._element.scaleX = 1;
        //  obj._element.scaleY = 1;
        //  console.log("Width Contenedor Imagen: "+obj.width+" Width Imagen: "+obj._element.width);
        //  console.log("Scale Contenedor Imagen: "+obj.scaleX+" Scale Imagen: "+obj._element.scaleX);
        //}
        obj.setCoords();
        //}
    });
});
```

**EDIT: New Discovery**

Speaking of text, rect, images and polylines, it seems that I am modifying an external container, because the inner content remains intact. How can I modify the size of that let's say, inner container?